# Ubuntu Black Sreen problem after upgrading from 18.04 to latest 20.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, permissions

I tried exactly like https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/ and did add "nomodeset" in the place of "quiet splash" the "ctrl+x" and now my pc is stuck into this :

[console image showing logs and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLi9d.jpg)

which is saying :

> Stopping User Manager for UID 122...
>
> [ok] Stopped Stopping User Manager for UID 122.
>
> Stopping User runtime directory /run/user/122...
>
> [ok] Stopped User runtime directory /run/user/122.
>
> [Failed] to start Docker Application Container Engine.
>
> See 'systemctl status docker.service for details'
>
> [ok] Reached target Multi-User System
>
> [ok] Reached target graphical interface
>
> [ok] Started stop unreadahead data collection 45s after completed
> startup
>
> Starting Update UTMP about Runlevel Changes...
>
> [ok] Finished Update UTMP about Sytem runlevel changes...

and keep stuck here. what should I do now? I should apply those temporary solution and then permanent but now I am stuck here and is this about docker or others and how can I get pass to this?

**Edit :** then I pressed "ctrl+alt+f5" and ran "sudo systemctl list-units --failed" which returned 2 failed unit :

1. docker.service (Application container engine - loaded + active failed + SUB failed)
2. docker.socket (Docker socket for the api - loaded + active failed + SUB failed )
   where,
   LOAD = reflects whether the unit defination was properly loaded,
   ACTIVE = The high level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB,
   SUB = The low level unit activation state, values depend on unit type

Now I can access my ubuntu 20.04.2 through terminal but still confused what to do next.
Thanx in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truly problem was a dpkg dependency problem which we solved with `sudo apt-get --reinstall gdm3` and `sudo systemctl enable gdm3`

Try with 'ctrl + alt + F5(or any other of the 12 keys)' till you get some login screen, there you log you in and give us your output of `sudo systemctl list-units --failed`

If you are in tty you can try the following:

`sudo systemctl enable gdm3`

`sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

also you can try `startx` from tty and look if your desktop appears.

also try:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

Comment: Thanx a lot for the response.. I just edited my question with the addition of the things you have asked

Comment: I also updated my answer. @NafiulAlamFuji

Comment: should I rather just remove or purge docker packages and then again do the same process? can restarting gdm3 cause any troubles?

Comment: restart gdm should nothing destroy, you don't must be uninstall docker I think to exclude docker as problem, is is enought to disable docker with: `sudo systemctl stop docker.service && sudo systemctl stop docker.socket && sudo systemctl disable docker.service && sudo systemctl disable docker.socket`

Comment: I just stopped and disabled docker service and docker socket and then ran "startx" but it is showing "xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/fuji/.Xauthority" and then after showing some quick texts got black screen again. what is happening and what to do now? and thanx for the helping..!!

Comment: now again back to command line with some infos.. "waiting for x server to shut down (II) server terminated successfully (0). closing log file.ily unavailabled MIT-MAGIC_COOKIE-1 key ..  xinit:server error xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/fuji/.Xauthority"

Comment: exist .Xauthority? try `ls -lsh ~/.Xauthority`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123035/discussion-between-lucki1000-and-nafiul-alam-fuji).

Comment: @luck100 srry for interrupting again.. everything was working fine but now i am facing ui rendering problem.. like mouse is lagging and everything is re rendering all the time which is makking laggy every other process and unable to work. I tried update then upgrade. but while upgrading it was showing like "could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend" :) what is happening :'(

Comment: @NafiulAlamFuji please post the full message

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 1514 (unattended-upgr)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: every time I move my mouse.. screen gets rendered slowly making me harder to even point in specific area

Comment: is the dpkg error still present if you perform a `sudo apt update`? and did you have a Nvidia, Amd or Intel graphics card?

Comment: no, apt-get update is not showing error.. but some critical finding,I have no extra dedicated graphics.. .. a command shows.. intel HD graphics 630 (edited)

Comment: and if you run sudo apt upgrade -y and restart after it's done, try if it is better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123119/discussion-between-nafiul-alam-fuji-and-lucki1000).